# Синтаксис замыканий в JS

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Первый раз столкнувшись с замыканиями и не зная, что это такое, пробовал синтаксически понять, что происходит в коде вида: (function(){})(). Известно, что конструкция "()" - это вызов функции. Возникал вопрос по поводу первых круглых скобок

Позже, проникнувшись темой, вопрос первых круглых скобок меня волновать не перестал. **Зачем они нужны, если без них всё работает?**

При этом ни одного примера в статьях про замыкания без применения первых круглых скобок я не видел.

Классический пример замыкания в JavaScript:

```
buttons[i].onclick = (function(a){
    return  function(){ console.log(a);}
})(i)
```

без первых скобок:

```
buttons[i].onclick = function(a){
         return function(){ console.log(a);}
}(i)
```

Зачем во всех примерах эти, получается лишние, синтаксические элементы?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ключевое слово `function` в js может употребляться в двух контекстах - это контекст объявления функции и контекст выражения, где это слово создает анонимную функцию.

Если строка начинается со слова `function` - то это объявление функции. С такой функцией нельзя ничего сразу же сделать (например, вызвать), кроме того, у нее должно быть имя.

```
function (a) { console.log(a) } (5) // Ошибка
```

Поэтому такую функцию во что-нибудь оборачивают:

```
+function (a) { console.log(a) } (5) // 5
!function (a) { console.log(a) } (5) // 5
~function (a) { console.log(a) } (5) // 5
(function (a) { console.log(a) }) (5) // 5
(function (a) { console.log(a) } (5)) // 5
```

Если же слово `function` стоит не в начале строки - то ничего делать и не надо, все будет прекрасно работать:

```
var a = function (a) { return 5 } (5)
```

Comment: _контекст выражения, где это слово создает анонимную функцию._ - не обязательно анонимную

Comment: _Если строка начинается со слова function - то это объявление функции._ - меня кстати недавно поправили с таким определением :-) тут лучше не строка, а _statement_, не знаю как получше перевести

Comment: @Grundy `statement` обычно переводят как "оператор". Но для данного языка это будет некорректно. Лучшее что я встречал - "логическая строка".

Comment: тут просто именно обычная строка не совсем корректно, например, `;function(){...}` вроде то же строка не начинается со слова function, но видно, что будет исключение

Answer (score 2):

Круглые скобки не обязательны, они лишь указывают что это не [объявление функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function), а [выражение с функцией](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), которое надо вычислить прямо на месте, поэтому вот это всё работает:

```
(function(){alert(1);})()
(function(){alert(1);}())
!function(){alert(1);}()
+function(){alert(1);}()
```

В вашем примере роль круглых скобок выполняет оператор присвоения, поэтому они там действительно не нужны. Обычно используются именно круглые скобки, потому что они не заставляют программу выполнять лишние телодвижения (из примеров выше - приводить функцию к числу или к булевому значению). Они нужны, когда вам не нужно с анонимной функцией ничего делать, кроме её вызова

Comment: а как еще может быть использована анонимная функция, если не через присваивание её при определении? (первые 2 строки вашего примера)

Comment: @MaximTronenko, чтобы выполнить, то что находится в теле функции

Comment: @Grundy, зачем может понадобиться такой кусок кода вообще оформлять в виде функции?

Comment: @MaximTronenko [вот так](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) например

Comment: @MaximTronenko, чтобы внутренние локальные переменные не сохранялись в глобальной области видимости

Answer (score 2):

Конструкции вида:

```
(function() {
  ...
})();
```

Это паттерн [Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). В JavaScript его принято использовать для разделения области видимости переменных - что бы случайно не наплодить глобальных переменных, которые впоследствии могут вызвать ошибки в других блоках кода.