# JavaScript. Создание объектов с приватными свойствами. Как?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Вникаю в ООП JavaScript. Пытаюсь разобратся в создании обектов с приватными методами и свойствами.

В JavaScript можно создавать обьекты через `new`

```
function Constructor() {
    var name = 'foo';
    this.get_name = function() {
        return name;
    }
}    
var foo = new Constructor();
```

А можно без

```
function ConstructorWithoutNew() {
    var name = 'bar';
    var that = {};
    that.get_name = function() {
        return name;
    }
    return that;
}
var bar = ConstructorWithoutNew();
```

Первый вопрос - есть ли принципиальная разница между этими подходами? При каких условиях стоит использовать тот или иной, или возможно есть третий, более универсальный/продуктивный/правильный?

Comment: в первом случае используется конструктор и будет работать instanceof оператор, во втором используется просто функция возвращающая объект

Comment: @Grundy тоесть в JavaScript все же можно создавать собственные типы?

Comment: а где-то было написано что нельзя? :)

Comment: А что вы понимаете под универсальный/продуктивный/правильный? Каковы критерии оценки?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev так вот дело в том что ранее я работал по шаблону - спроектировал в UML, накидал интерфейсы, реализовал их в классах, через new создаю экземпляры. А тут... можно создавать через литерал обьекта, или через функцию конструктор... понять бы какую технику когда применять

Comment: А вы попробуйте реализовать наследование и все сразу станет ясно ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev так в том то и проблема что при создании через литерал наследуемся через присваивание свойству `__proto__` обьекта наследника, при создании через функцию конструктор - свойству `prototype`. Получается что тоже ничего не понятно

Comment: Как вариант использования в качестве приватного свойства: `this[Symbol(name)] = 'foo';` Преимущества: Не участвует в итерации в `for..in`, недоступен через `Object.keys(foo)` и `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo)`. Как вариант, может вообще не стоит "заморачиваться", обозначайте `_protected` свойства/методы. Что ж, по крайней мере, тех, кто захочет стрелять себе в ногу, вы предупредите...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница этих подходов в том, что в первом случае активируются механизмы наследования в js, а во втором случае - используются механизмы утиной типизации.

При использовании второго способа не будет работать оператор instanceof - зато так можно "унаследоваться" от функции, чего нельзя нормально сделать с прототипами.

Но оба способа не являются идеальными - в каждом из них создается отдельный метод на каждый экземпляр объекта. При (ошибочной) попытке применить такой метод на "чужой" экземпляр объекта через `call` или `apply` возможны странные вещи, которые будут не сразу очевидны.

Поэтому самый современный способ создания приватный полей - через символы. Кратко: вызов `Symbol("...")` даст вам некоторый объект, который можно использовать в качестве имени поля, при этом повторный вызов функции `Symbol` даст уже новый объект. То есть, если "спрятать" символ - то и поле окажется приватным.

Вот пример, здесь символ "спрятан" при помощи паттерна "модуль":

```
var Constructor;
!function() {
    var sName = Symbol("name")
    Constructor = function Constructor() { }
    Constructor.prototype[sName] = "foo"
    Constructor.prototype.get_name = function() {
        return this[sName];
    }
}()
var foo = new Constructor();
```

Переменная `sName` не видна за пределами модуля - а потому и доступа к приватному полю `name` снаружи нет, хотя внутри модуля к нему обращаться довольно просто.

Поддерживаются символы на момент написания этого ответа, к сожалению, только Хромом и Огнелисом из основных браузеров. Но для других браузеров (IE) можно использовать полифил:

```
!function() {
    if (typeof window.Symbol === "function") return;

    var counter = 0;
    window.Symbol = function (name) {
      return "__" + name + "@" + ++counter;
    }
}()
```

Такой символ **не будет** обладать большинством свойств "настоящих" символов - но для создания почти-приватных переменных вполне пойдет.

Comment: А почему бы не возвращать конструктор из замыкания вместо использования глобальной переменной в первом вашем примере?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev возвращать-то можно, но куда его потом сохранить?  В глобальную переменную? А какая разница? :)

Comment: Большая, содержимое замыкания не будет зависеть от имени переменной `Constructor`. Ну и при создании отдельного файла под модуль, отдельная глобальная переменная просто не нужна: `module.exports = !function() {....`

Comment: @DmitriySimushev в данном же случае я использовал такую конструкцию потому что она позволяет вернуть из модуля несколько значений без изменения остальных частей программы, что полезно при постепенном переходе на модули.

Comment: Так я же не пытаюсь убедить вас, что ваш подход не верен. Просто перфекционизм, все дела))

Comment: Да, согласен, при правильном подходе модули готовятся немного иначе. Особенно асинхронные (хотя стандарт ES6 их уже прожевал). Но вопрос был все-таки про наследование.

Comment: AMD -- скорее мертв, чем жив. Пора жить дальше.

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо, изучая Ваши примеры не могу вьехать в следующее. Вы перед функцией оберткой модуля ставите `!` . Зачем? Что оно дает не могу понять

Comment: @totorro http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/483559/178779

Comment: @totorro такой синтаксис применяется для того, чтобы объявить функцию и сразу же ее вызвать. Результат - дополнительная область видимости для локальных переменных.

Comment: @totorro, а можно было вместо `!` просто в круглые скобки эту функцию взять :) например: `(function(){...})()` возможно было бы понятнее

Comment: @Grundy по ссылке есть такой вариант

Comment: @PavelMayorov, по ссылкам не ходи @ комментарии пиши :-D

Comment: Зачем здесь вообще симбол? Достаточно `var sName = 'sName';`, либо вообще во всех обращаниях использовать `'sName'`.

Comment: @user23398 затем, что с вашим способом свойство не будет приватным - его можно будет поменять в любом месте программы

Comment: Понял, спасибо.