# Зачем нужен Symbol в JavaScript и как правльно его использовать?

Tags: javascript

Знаю о Symbol примитиве, но совсем не понимаю его прямого назначение. 
Читал, что его можно использовать при создании полифилов.

*Вопрос*:

1. Как правльно использовать Symbol при создании полифила?
2. Что дает использование Symbol при создании полифила?

вот , к примеру у меня есть полифил

```
if (!Object.values) {
  Object.values = function values(O) {
    return reduce(keys(O), (v, k) => concat(v, typeof k === 'string' && isEnumerable(O, k) ? [O[k]] : []), []);
  };
}
```

как его использовать с Символом?

Comment: _Читал, что его можно использовать при создании полифилов._ - где читал? Там должен был быть пример использования.

Answer (score 2):

Спецификация определяет значение [`Symbol`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-symbol-value) как

> primitive value that represents a unique, non-String Object property key

> примитивное значение, которое позволяет определять *уникальный*, не строковый ключ, для свойства объекта.

[Тип `Symbol`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-symbol-type) в свою очередь, это набор всех не строковых значений, которые могут быть использованы в качестве ключа для свойства объекта.

Каждое возможное значение `Symbol` - **уникально** и **неизменяемо**.

---

В спецификации значения `Symbol` активно используются для объявления *специальных* методов. Такие значения считаются *общеизвестными* и [собраны в отдельной таблице](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-well-known-symbols)

Примерами таких значений являются:

- `Symbol.hasInstance`, который позволяет определять работу оператора `instanceof`. Например:

  ```js
  var Base = {};
  Base[Symbol.hasInstance] = function(val) {
    return true;
  }

  console.log(1 instanceof Base);
  console.log('1'
    instanceof Base);
  console.log({}
    instanceof Base);
  ```
- `Symbol.iterator`, который позволяет определять как получать итератор, который потом будет использовать в цикле `for..of`, при использовании `spread` оператора `[...obj]` и т.д.
- `Symbol.toStringTag`, который влияет на то, что будет выводить [`Object.prototype.toString`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-object.prototype.tostring) метод

  ```js
  var Base = {};
  Base[Symbol.toStringTag] = "Base"

  console.log(Base.toString());
  console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(Base));
  ```

И другие.

---

Еще одно применение значений `Symbol` - имитация *приватных* полей. Подробнее об этом в ответах к вопросу: [JavaScript. Создание объектов с приватными свойствами. Как?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/522068/186999).

Однако это является лишь имитацией, так как, хотя поля с ключом типа `Symbol` пропускаются при проходе в цикле `for..in`, их все равно можно получить с помощью методов `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` и `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`