Я не понимаю конструкцию языка
В данный момент я прохожу туториал по next js.
В одном из файлов мне встретилось следующее:
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';

/* какой-то код */

export async function fetchRevenue() {
  try {
    /* какой-то код */
    const data = await sql<Revenue>`SELECT * FROM revenue`;
    /* какой-то код */
  } catch (error) {
    /* какой-то код */
  }
}

Определение sql примерно следующее:
declare const sql: VercelPool & (<O extends QueryResultRow>(strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...values: Primitive[]) => Promise<QueryResult<O>>);

Кто-нибудь объясните пожалуйста вот это действие:
await sql<Revenue>`SELECT * FROM revenue`;
почему после sql стоит строка в обратных кавычках

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates

всё, понял, это теговый шаблон. Спасибо большое

Это обычная асинхронная теггирующая функция. Как f2 или f3, только ещё от тайпскрипта generic-параметр добавился между ней и строкой.


~async function() {
  function f1(strs, ...vals) {
    return strs[0]
  }

  console.log(f1 `abc`)

  function f2(strs, ...vals) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, strs[0]))
  }

  console.log(await f2 `def`)
  
  async function f3(strs, ...vals) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
    return strs[0]
  }
  
  console.log(await f3 `hij`)  
}()



PS: Как собрать строку в интерполяторе?

А ~async function это что? Я сегодня что-то слишком много нового узнал. ))

@eccs0103, один из способов записи самовызывающейся функции. В данном случае асинхронной. Кажется, я где-то уже давал ответ по поводу самовызывающихся функций, но не могу найти...

При обнаружении, прошу дать ссылку. Интересовало

@eccs0103, ну не ищется... Это лучшее, что нашёл: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483571/178988.

Сойдет :)
